# SQL Server 2008 Management Studio - view change tracking data changes

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, change-tracking

I am using SQL Server 2008 Management Studio and want to view changes made to the data. I have enabled Change Tracking on the database and on specific tables.

My question is how do I view the changes made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some function to retrieve the changes such as `CHANGETABLE()`

take a look at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280358%28v=sql.105%29.aspx